# 301 Redirect Regex Pattern

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to make a IIS redirect rule to redirect from this url pattern, but it beats me:

https://www.mycompanyPLC.com/en/lorem/ipsum/whatever

to

https://www.mycompanyLTD.com/lorem/ipsum/whatever

Basically I need to replace PLC with LTD and if there is the "/en/" group in url, this has to be removed.

Comment: Does ```\en\``` always comes after ```.com```?

Comment: @Mandy8055 For this rule, yes. There's another scenario in which "/en/" is not present, but I'm creating another rule for that case.

Comment: I like your answer, comprehensive and well explained.

Comment: @Mandy8055 if you could have look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579295/iis-rewrite-rules-for-languages-and-new-domains I'd be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried using the regex which I suggested in my answer? If you'll do it will work for sure.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes, I've added details below.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your both the requirements using the single regex provided `/en/` is preceded by `.com`. Something like:

```
(.*?)PLC\.com(?:\/\ben\b)?(.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(.*?)`** - Represents 1st capturing group capturing everything before `PLC` **lazily**.
- **`PLC\.com`** - Matches `PLC.com` literally.
- **`(?:\/\ben\b)?`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching `\en` literally zero or one time. `\b` represents a [**word boundary.**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- **`(.*)`** - Represents the second capturing group matching everything after `\en` **greedily**.
- **`$1LTD.com$2`** - For the replacement(or redirection in this case) part you can get away with this string where `$1` represents the first captured group and `$2` represents the second captured group. In your case; you can use `{R:1}LTD.com{R:2}`.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/GFAeas/5)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below URL rule.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="en(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mycompanyLTD.com{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

There is no need to match a `/en` URL fragment forcibly. We redirect the request as long as we found that we have a `/en` URL segment. so does the `http/https` URL segment.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Can you please have look into this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579295/iis-rewrite-rules-for-languages-and-new-domains ?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of lecturing Regex I've created this rule and seems to be working (I've tested several scenarios):

```
^(http|https)://?(www.)mycompanyPLC.com/en?(.*)
```

and the Redirect URL from IIS is:

```
https://www.mycompanyLTD.com/{R:3}
```

Later edit:

The rule in IIS is like this:

```
<rule name="Replace PLC with LTD and remove /en/" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*?)PLC\.com(?:\/\ben\b)?(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}ltd.com{R:2}" />
                </rule>
```

Test urls were this format:

```
http://webdev.myCompanyplc.com/en/our-experience/retail
{R:1} = http://webdev.myCompany
{R:2} = /our-experience/retail
```

Regex expression was ok, but redirect still didnt work

Comment: Did you used case indifferent mode? i.e. `-i` flag? Because `PLC` is case sensitive and in your example you're using `plc`. Something like `ignoreCase="true"`