# IIS Rewrite rules for languages and new domains

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I need to create some rules (I thought that 2 would suffice) for the following scenarios:

A. First scenario

https://www.mydomainOLD.com/en/lorem/ipsum/doloret/etc to https://www.mydomainNEW.com/lorem/ipsum/doloret/etc

Basically, I need to change the domain from **mydomainOLD** to **mydomainNEW** and remove "/en/" from URL when it appears.

The rule I created is the following:

```
<rule name="Replace OLD with NEW and remove /en/" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(http|https)://?(www.)mydomainOLD.com/en?(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomainNEW.com/{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

B. Second scenario:

https://es.mydomainOLD.com/en/lorem/ipsum/doloret/etc to https://es.mydomainNEW.com/en/lorem/ipsum/doloret/etc

In this case, instead of "es" I can have other countries as well (fr, de, hk, etc.)

The rule I created is the following (for each country):

```
 <rule name="ES redirect from OLD to NEW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)es.mydomainOLD(.*)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}be.mydomainNEW.com{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
```

None of these rules are not working as I wanted, even if when I test the regex they work as expected. I think there's something more on the Condition Input that I'm missing. A bit of help would be more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Avoid common mistakes, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 and then learn how to troubleshoot via FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

Please try this rule for /en/

```
 <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/en/(.*)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www.)?mydomainOLD.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomainNEW.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

For somelike old/en/ to new/en/ or old/fr to old/fr, please apply this one.

```
   <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/([a-z]{2}/.*)" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="es.mydomainOLD.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://es.mydomainNEW.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

Update:
If you need to redirect (es/fr/de/hk).mydomainold.com to (es/fr/de/hk).mydomainnew.com. Please try this

```
      <rule name="rewrite rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([a-zA-Z]{2})\.mydomainOLD.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.mydomainNEW.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: Thank you, first rule helped. The second didn't try yet.

Comment: @iusmar I just update the rule. Please check if it achieve your requirement

Comment: What rule should I add for the querystring, because links like these: https://mydomainOLD.com/en/news?page=32&category=&view=current are redirected to https://mydomainNEW/news

Comment: Because your rule  appendQueryString="false". If you want to redirect to  mydomainNEW.com/en/news?page=32&category=&view=current, it should be appendQueryString="true"

Comment: Thanks Jokies Ding. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For scenario #1:

```
<rule name="General redirect - all urls - from OLD to NEW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomainOLD\.com(.*)$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/en/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomainNEW.com/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

For scenario #2:
One rule for each country (Fr in this example):

```
<rule name="France redirect - all urls - from OLD to NEW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^fr.mydomainOLD\.com(.*)$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://fr.mydomainOLD.com/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```